# How to correctly select the first item from a filtered collection?

Tags: category, collection

I'm trying to write a script to get a category given its path, which seems like it should be easy to do. As a test, I have a base category with an ID of 2, and it has 2 children, 'Foo' and 'Bar'. I'm using this code to try to get the 'Foo' category:

```
// Get the 'base' category.
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(2);
// Try to filter it out so that I only get 'Foo'
$category = $category->getChildrenCategories()->addFieldToFilter('name', 'Foo');
```

At this point, calling `print_r($category->getData());` shows that it should be doing what I want:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 16
            [entity_type_id] => 3
            [attribute_set_id] => 0
            [parent_id] => 2
            [created_at] => 2016-06-25 22:47:23
            [updated_at] => 2016-06-25 22:47:23
            [path] => 1/2/16
            [position] => 2
            [level] => 2
            [children_count] => 28
            [request_path] =>
            [is_active] => 1
            [name] => Foo
        )

)
```

There is 1 item in the collection, and it's the one I'm looking for. However, then I do:

```
$category = $category->getFirstItem();
print_r($category->getData());
```

I expect it to select the 'Foo' category, but it's selecting the 'Bar' category instead:

```
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 5
    [entity_type_id] => 3
    [attribute_set_id] => 0
    [parent_id] => 2
    [created_at] => 2016-06-25 22:42:19
    [updated_at] => 2016-06-25 22:42:19
    [path] => 1/2/5
    [position] => 1
    [level] => 2
    [children_count] => 87
    [request_path] => 
    [is_active] => 1
    [name] => Bar
    [url_key] => bar
    [is_anchor] => 1
)
```

I'm assuming at this point that `getFirstItem()` just gets the first item in the whole collection and ignores the filters, but I can't seem to find any documentation for it (although it's used in just about every example I've found). This method [doesn't seem to exist in the collection class](http://doc4dev.net/doc/Magento/1/class-Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection.html).

Am I missing a step somewhere? Where can I find the documentation for this method?

**Update:** I forgot to mention, but this is in Magento 1.9

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`getFirstItem()` is defined in `Varien_Data_Collection` which is the data source independent base class for all collections:

```
/**
 * Retrieve collection first item
 *
 * @return Varien_Object
 */
public function getFirstItem()
{
    $this->load();

    if (count($this->_items)) {
        reset($this->_items);
        return current($this->_items);
    }

    return new $this->_itemObjectClass();
}
```

It does what you think it does, loads the collection (if not already loaded) and returns the first item. **getFirstItem() is not your problem.**

---

**Although you *should* always call `setPageSize(1)` before `getFirstItem()`, *if you only need the first item*, otherwise all items that match the filters are loaded which can easily hurt performance.**

---

The problem is that `getChildrenCategories()` immediately **loads** the children collection, so filters that you add afterwards do not have any effect.

Now there is one additional trap, that you fell into: `getData()` on collections works different from other methods. It does not check if the collection is loaded, instead it checks if the `_data` property is empty. **When you load a collection, `_data` is not populated, only when you call `getData()`!**

```
public function getData()
{
    if ($this->_data === null) {


        $this->_renderFilters()
             ->_renderOrders()
             ->_renderLimit();
        /**
         * Prepare select for execute
         * @var string $query
         */
        $query       = $this->_prepareSelect($this->getSelect());
        $this->_data = $this->_fetchAll($query, $this->_bindParams);
        $this->_afterLoadData();
    }
    return $this->_data;
}
```

This results in a second database query as soon as you call `getData()` and this time, your new filter is applied. But it does not change the `_items` property, so your previously loaded result is still used for everything else.

By the way, I still did not come across any reasonable use case for this method. It's used internally by `load()` but probably should not have been public. The core doesn't use it from outside the collection class anywhere as far as I see.

### Solution

Clear the collection (which resets `_items` and marks it as not loaded):

```
$category->getChildrenCategories()->clear()->setPageSize(1)->getFirstItem();
```

Comment: "you should always call setPageSize(1) before, if you only need the first item"  <-- That should highlighted, emphasized, and bolded.  I have seen, more than once, entire product catalogs loaded in memory because this was neglected.

Comment: @KevinSchroeder you're right, I highlighted it a little.

Comment: Needs more cowbell

Comment: Absolutely effing ridiculous.