# Magento 2.1 : How to extend Product listing in your custom product list and apply SKU Filter

Tags: magento2, collection, magento-2.1, product-collection

I have a Custom module which have customer mapped with certain products , I want to show a custom listing of those products with layered navigation

After Extending product list block in my custom block and changing

```
public function getLoadedProductCollection()
    {
             return $this->_getProductCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('sku',array('nin'=> $this->getSku()));
    }
```

On `list.phtml`

```
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
print_r($_productCollection->getData());
echo"</pre>";
```

give a Filter collection, But when i Iterate it with

```
foreach ($_productCollectionTest as $_productTest) {
    echo"<pre>";
    print_r($_productTest->getData());
    echo"</pre>";
}
```

I get a unfiltered Result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added the filter after the collection was **already loaded**.

Then in your test code, you fell into the "collection->getData()" trap, that i explained in [How to correctly select the first item from a filtered collection?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123011/how-to-correctly-select-the-first-item-from-a-filtered-collection/123160#123160)

> This results in a second database query as soon as you call `getData()` and this time, your new filter is applied. But it does not change the `_items` property, so your previously loaded result is still used for everything else.
>
> By the way, I still did not come across any reasonable use case for this method. It's used internally by `load()` but probably should not have been public. The core doesn't use it from outside the collection class anywhere as far as I see.

## Solution

Clear the collection (which resets `_items` and marks it as not loaded):

```
public function getLoadedProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_getProductCollection();
    $collection->clear();
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku',array('nin'=> $this->getSku()));
    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: Will this server my purpose of further filtering the collection , after layered filters are already applied

Comment: Yes, `clear()` does not remove the existing filters it just makes the collection reload itself the next time it is iteratred.

Comment: @fschmengler I am facing an issue of layered navigation for custom collection please advise. I have posted question here [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142562/how-to-update-category-page-with-custom-filters-and-also-layered-navigation-ma)