# Get first subcategory name in category

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I need get first subcategory name in current category how in admin panel. How it possible.

Update:

```
<?php 
    $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
    $_category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
    $currentCategoryId= $_category->getId();
    $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($currentCategoryId);
    foreach ($children as $category)
    {
          echo $category->getName();
    }
    ?>
```

with this code i can get all subcategory name in current category, but i need get only first subcategory name - not all list subcategory name

Comment: Could you spell out a little more clear what version of magento you are using what you are trying to do, what is the end goal. You question is far to vague to have a clear answer.

Comment: i'm use magento 1.9 version, i have category Auto, with subcategories and i need get only first subcategory name in category Auto

Comment: Are you wanting to rename a category Auto? Or are you wanting to create a subcategory named Auto?

Comment: i need in my template phtml get first subcategory name in category Auto, with this code: $_category_detail=Mage::registry('current_category'); i can get category name Auto, but i need first subcategory in category Auto

Comment: please update your question with the code that you are using, once we see that, should be able to help troubleshoot it.

Comment: i did this, please look

Comment: Can´t you do $firstItem = $children->getFirstItem(); and then echo $firstItem

Comment: $firstItem working for products, but not working for subcategory

Comment: @Lerry check this one here might be helpful http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123011/how-to-correctly-select-the-first-item-from-a-filtered-collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the code below to get first subcategory name in the current category

```
<?php 

    $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
    $_category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();    
    $currentCategoryId= $_category->getId();    
    $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($currentCategoryId,0,false,true);           
    $firstsubcategory =  $children->getFirstItem(); // First Sub Catehory
    echo $firstsubcategory->getName()."<br /><br />";;
    foreach ($children as $category)
    {
          echo $category->getName()."<br />";
    }
    ?>
```