# Call to undefined method Collection::getData()

Tags: magento-1.9, database, collection, model

I use (Manthan_Marketplace) extension in my Magento store
I want to add a table to this extension
 so create a custom table (photos) in Magento database with name:(`manthan_marketplace_photos`) 
Table photos structure:
      user_id.....................img_url
(id of user, primary).............(image name, text)

and edit `config.xml` in (`app\code\community\Manthan\Marketplace\etc\config.xml`):

```
    <models>
        <marketplace>
            <class>Manthan_Marketplace_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>marketplace_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </marketplace>
        <marketplace_mysql4>
            <class>Manthan_Marketplace_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <seller>
                    <table>manthan_marketplace_seller</table>
                </seller>
                <photos>
                   <table>manthan_marketplace_photos</table><= I add this code 
                </photos>
                <vendorproduct>
                    <table>manthan_marketplace_vendorproduct</table>
                </vendorproduct>
                <review>
                    <table>manthan_marketplace_review</table>
                </review>
                <rating>
                    <table>manthan_marketplace_rating</table>
                </rating>
                <sellerrate>
                    <table>manthan_marketplace_seller_rated</table>
                </sellerrate>
                <payment>
                    <table>manthan_marketplace_payment</table>
                </payment>
            </entities>
        </marketplace_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <marketplace_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Manthan_Marketplace</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </marketplace_setup>
        <marketplace_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </marketplace_write>
        <marketplace_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </marketplace_read>
    </resources>..................some more code
```

Then I create a Photos.php in (`app\code\community\Manthan\Marketplace\Model`):

```
class Manthan_Marketplace_Model_Photos extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {  
        protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init("marketplace/photos");
    }

}
```

and create Photos.php in(`app\code\community\Manthan\Marketplace\Model\Mysql4`):

```
class Manthan_Marketplace_Model_Mysql4_Photos extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract {
    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('marketplace/photos', 'user_id');
    }

}
```

and after that create Collection.php in(`app\code\community\Manthan\Marketplace\Model\Mysql4\Photos`):

```
class Manthan_Marketplace_Model_Mysql4_Photos_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract {
    public function _construct() {
        $this->_init('marketplace/photos');
    }

}
```

now when i use tis code :

```
$img = Mage::getModel('marketplace/photos');
   var_dump($img);
```

it return:

> object(Manthan_Marketplace_Model_Photos)#60 (15) { ["_eventPrefix":protected]=> string(13) "core_abstract" ["_eventObject":protected]=> string(6) "object" ["_resourceName":protected]=> string(18) "marketplace/photos" ["_resource":protected]=> NULL ["_resourceCollectionName":protected]=> string(29) "marketplace/photos_collection" ["_cacheTag":protected]=> bool(false) ["_dataSaveAllowed":protected]=> bool(true) ["_isObjectNew":protected]=> NULL ["_data":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_hasDataChanges":protected]=> bool(false) ["_origData":protected]=> NULL ["_idFieldName":protected]=> NULL ["_isDeleted":protected]=> bool(false) ["_oldFieldsMap":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_syncFieldsMap":protected]=> array(0) { } }

but when i use this code:

```
 $result=$img->getCollection()->getData();
```

return:

> Call to undefined method Manthan_Marketplace_Model_Mysql4_Photos_Collection::getData()

why getData() is undefined for this one but is ok for another model?
thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your collection should extend `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract`, not `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract`.

But be careful with `Collection::getData()`. I described the pitfalls with this method here: [How to correctly select the first item from a filtered collection?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123011/how-to-correctly-select-the-first-item-from-a-filtered-collection/123160#123160)

> `getData()` on collections works different from other methods. It does
>   not check if the collection is loaded, instead it checks if the
>   `_data` property is empty. **When you load a collection, `_data` is
>   not populated, only when you call `getData()`!**
>
> [...]
>
> This results in a second database query as soon as you call
>   `getData()` and this time, your new filter is applied. But it does not
>   change the `_items` property, so your previously loaded result is
>   still used for everything else.
>
> By the way, I still did not come across any reasonable use case for
>   this method. It's used internally by `load()` but probably should not
>   have been public. The core doesn't use it from outside the collection
>   class anywhere as far as I see.

Use `getItems()` instead to inspect the items of the collection.

Comment: Performance for `getData()` ... https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/179035/46249

Answer (score 4):

Try updating **app\code\community\Manthan\Marketplace\Model\Mysql4\Photos.php**

```
class Manthan_Marketplace_Model_Mysql4_Photos extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract {
    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('marketplace/photos', 'user_id');
    }

}
```

And **app\code\community\Manthan\Marketplace\Model\Mysql4\Photos\Collection.php**

```
class Manthan_Marketplace_Model_Mysql4_Photos_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract {
    public function _construct() {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('marketplace/photos');
    }

}
```